# How to declare 2D array in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multidimensional-array

I am new to iPhone. I tried a lot to declare 2D array but I am unable to get the result.

```
NSMutableArray *outerarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
outerarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"10-20","21-30","31-40","41-50","51-60","61-70","71-80","81-90","91-100",nil,
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"10-20","21-30","31-40","41-50","51-60","61-70","71-80","81-90","91-100",nil],
    nil];
```

I want to combine two arrays elements and compare it with other element.

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@"..."` is an `NSString`. `"..."` is not, it's a C string constant. You need to use the `@"..."` syntax for all `NSString` objects you're putting into an `NSArray`.

Comment: I have already tried it but It was not working. It was not showing any error but also not showing the combined result. I tried to retrive the values by the following code in a nested for loop.               NSMutableArray  *stg=[[outerarray objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j];

Comment: `[[outerarray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j]` will give you an `NSString`, not an `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

NS[Mutable]Array does not support 2D as far as I know. You can probably jury-rig it to mutate and access elements in 2D (make that its own class). Once you can access arbitrary elements, you can "combine" them and compare them as you need. The alternative is since Objective-C is a superset of C, its `int arrayName [][]` is available (but discouraged).